# How to fix sonar issue for Replace this usage of Sun classes by ones from the Java API?

Tags: java, sonarqube

I ran into the sonar issue with the following import code

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.Builder;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.representation.Form;
```

Which JAVA classes shall I use to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule will match any classe from "com.sun" packages. This rule can be configured to exclude jersey classes.

You may have more details about this in this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/sonarqube/0Ys3k1UI_lw/n3QCaQM7BgAJ)